# WebSphere 8 shared library white screen bug

Tags: websphere, shared-libraries, websphere-8

In WebSphere 8 after I've added a shared library to my installed Java EE application and clicked "Ok",
I'm always getting a white screen instead of the normal WebSphere workflow (WebSphere 8 should connect the shared library with the application and ask me if I want to save changes).

Server's SystemErr.log:

```
[4/4/13 18:15:20:356 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[4/4/13 18:15:20:357 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.AppManagementHelper.validateAndUpdate(AppManagementHelper.java:329)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:357 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.MapSharedLibForModAction.execute(MapSharedLibForModAction.java:378)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:357 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:357 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:357 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:358 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:950)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:499)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:320)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:359 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:360 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:361 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:364 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[4/4/13 18:15:20:364 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:364 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:364 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:365 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:950)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:499)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:320)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:366 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:367 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:368 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:369 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[4/4/13 18:15:20:369 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.AppManagementHelper.getNextStep(AppManagementHelper.java:147)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:369 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.MapSharedLibForModAction.execute(MapSharedLibForModAction.java:391)
[4/4/13 18:15:20:369 MSK] 00000051 SystemErr     R  ... 35 more
```

But:

1. Adding a shared library as part of the installation process (stage 4 of "Java EE application installation" process) finishes with success.
2. In WebSphere 7 both ways of adding a shared library work fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs when you get the whitescreen?

Comment: Thx, I've added SystemErr.log

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to install was 8.5.x, in this up-to-date version my problem vanished.